# Read MySQL fixed number of rows from last at frequent intervals

Tags: mysql

I have a database with network data, each row corresponding to a packet/flow. I want to read the data from last to top in a fixed interval, say 15 mins of data at a time and do some forensics processing on it.

So my questions related to MySQL:
Is there anyway in which I can keep keep track of till where I have read data?
Can some one help me with sql query for "Read last 15 mins of data, then next 15 mins of data, and so on" by reading the first column, which contains the timestamp of SYN packet.?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to keep a variable to store where you left off. Whether you store this in your app, or in a client var in MySQL is up to you, but it would be something like this using a server-side variable:

```
select @previously_finished_at := now()
```

... do your analysis on whatever data was retrieved ...

```
select @new_end_point := date_add(@previously_finished_at, interval 15 minutes)

select the,fields,you,want
from
table
where packet_timestamp between @previous_finished_at and @new_end_point;

select @previous_finished_at := @new_end_point
```

So, if you started this at `2011-01-01 00:00:00`, then your first query would have

```
...
where packet_timestamp between '2011-01-01 00:00:00' and '2011-01-01 00:15:00'
```

then, on your next run, would be come

```
...
where packet_timestamp between '2011-01-01 00:15:00' and '2011-01-01 00:30:00'
```

and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have limited knowledge in SQL related stuff, so i had trouble figuring it out.

Comment: I think, date_add unit syntax is minute and not minutes. Edited.